# Datatables having issue with ngFor

Tags: html, typescript, datatables, angular2-forms

I am using Datatables (https://datatables.net/) with an Angular2 theme.

The issue which I am facing is that if using static  I get perfect and desired response, but if I am creating  dynamically from an Api response using `ngFor` the UI is broken and getting `Data not found in table`. Can any one  tell me what's the issue?

Works perfect if:

```
<tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>sdfDamon</td>
                        <td>sdf5516 Adolfo Green</td>
                        <td>Littsdfsdfelhaven</td>
                        <td>8sdfsdf5</td>
                        <td>2014/sfsdf06/13</td>
                        <td>$553sfsdf,sdf536</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Torrerrrrry</td>
                        <td>19</td>
                        <td>Westsdfsdf Sedrickstad</td>
                        <td>7sdf7</td>
                        <td>2014/09/12</td>
                        <td>$243,577</td>
                    </tr></tbody>
```

Issue if using as :

```
<tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let dd of d">
                            <td>{{dd.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{dd.q}}</td>
                            <td>{{dd.w}}</td>
                            <td>{{dd.e}}</td>
                            <td>{{dd.r}}</td>
                            <td>{{dd.t}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Perhaps because `d` is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for replying, in my case I was creating datatables using jQuery in Angular2, So first Datatables were created then I was setting data in angular var through api so I was getting "Not Found".

Calling datagrid in api success resolved my issue. Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

First try putting `dd?.` before each of the `td`s. This may cover the case you don't have some info from your DB
second, when are you initializing `d`? probably it will not exist by the time you rub the `*ngFor`, so try wrapping the table with `*ngIf="d"`